# Загрузить картинку в собственный пакет компонентов

Tags: delphi, package, vcl

Есть пакет компонентов `*.bpk`. В нем я реализую свои кастомные компоненты. В одном из них мне нужно использовать картинку `*.png` из rc файла. Вот его содержимое:

```
INFO RCDATA info.png
DELETE RCDATA delete.png
```

я компилирую в `ChartIcon.res` и пытаюсь его подключить к проекту пакета. В ресурсхакере видно что ресурсы присутствуют:

```
   package SpComponents;
   {$R ChartIcon.res}`
    ...
    ...
    ..
```

в модуле где определен компонент я пытаюсь загрузить ресурс:

```
FInfoButton.Glyph.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'INFO');
```

Но выдает ошибку что ресурс не найден. Как правильно загрузить ресурс в пакете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите тип `FInfoButton.Glyph`. Не исключено, что класс ищет ресурс типа `RCBITMAP`, а не `RCDATA`. Попробуйте создать `TPngImage` и грузить через него. Плюс попробуйте `FindClassHInstance`, а то `HInstance` может дать не тот модуль.

Comment: да действительно перекомпилировал rc с `INFO BITMAP INFO.bmp
DELETE BITMAP DELETE.bmp`  и при загрузке сделал `FInfoButton.Glyph.LoadFromResourceName(FindClassHInstance(TChartEx), 'INFO');`  и заработало